# Realistic model of bias voltage (battery) and diode in high frequency circuit

Tags: diodes, circuit-design, ltspice

I try to add a bias voltage to my AC circuit, however in high frequency the added battery causes increase of reflection so I am trying to use a diode in series with my battery to avoid that reflection. But in general I don’t know why the battery causes that reflection and I am looking for the realistic internal model (LTspice) of battery and diode to make sure they would not add unwanted resonance.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! What is “reflection” in this context?

Comment: In RF design, however, we must always be aware of the fact that signals can travel in both directions: from source to load, certainly, but also—because of reflections—from load to source, [link](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/radio-frequency-analysis-design/real-life-rf-signals/understanding-reflections-and-standing-waves-rf-circuit-design/)

Comment: You might want to consider a choke instead.

Comment: If source and load are matched to the transmission line there are no reflections, so if adding a battery causes reflections it must be changing the impedance. Please show us your LTspice circuit so we can see where and how this is happening.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. I didn’t think RF immediately when you said high frequency.

Comment: At the simplest you'll have a few Farad capacitor with up to a few Ohms series resistance. By itself, this will not cause any reflections in any RF circuit, so you may want to consider that those reflections are due to the parasitics and maybe improper decoupling. There are various battery models in SPICE, but they are only approximations for their capacity and discharge rate. I don't think there are models that deal with high frequency behaviour (but I don't know them all).